# Configure Google Analytics Report to default to Page Title rather than Page URL

Tags: configuration, google-analytics

We have Google Analytics working, 
When you go to the Behaviour --> Site Content --> All Pages section there is a timeline followed by a table.

The default setting for the Table is Primary Dimension = Page, we want the default to be Page Title

Does anyone know how we can configure this? We have looked at all the help files and googled our query to no success.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a custom report where the primary dimension is page title and the metrics are pageviews, unique pageviews, avg. time on page, entrances, bounce rate, % exit, and page value.

[image]

**EDIT:** This question would be more suited on the Stackoverflow - Webmasters too, as it doesn't directly relate to programming.